# How to compile vuejs source code to a single html file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple vuejs project, which does not need to communicate with server. I need to pass this project to someone does not know software engineering, so I cannot have him install nodejs and run `npm run dev` to run this project. Is there any way to compile this project to a single html file, so he can just open this file in chrome and run it?

Comment: check this out: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN and write your code in html script tag. I think it is simple way. If the project is too big, I cannot sure it is possible to code in single file.

Comment: use vuejs cdn link into html file. checkout this one: https://coligo.io/vuejs-the-basics/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show him the project (and don't let him edit it), the obvious solution is to create a build (running npm run build), put it on a test server and give him the domain name. Another possibility is to send him (e.g. via mail, zipped) the content of the dist folder after a build (the index.html and the static folder).